# Javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'ticket_id' not found on type java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nhibernate-mapping, jsp-tags

The datatype for TICKET_ID column is int in DB. Still the problem persists.Set the getter/setters public too.

Model

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TICKET_ID")
private Integer ticket_id;



public Integer getTicket_id() {
    return ticket_id;
}

public void setTicket_id(Integer ticket_id) {
    this.ticket_id = ticket_id;
}


@Column(name = "PRIORITY")
private String priority;
```

HQL

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    String hql = "Select ticket_id from Ticket";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Ticket> ticketList = session.createQuery(hql)
            .list();
    session.close();
    return ticketList;
```

JSP

```
<th>Category</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${ticketList}" var="usr">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${usr.ticket_id}" /></td>
                            <td>Priority</td>
```

Exception

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'ticket_id' not found on type java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is

```
select ticket_id from Ticket
```

That query returns a `List<Integer>` containing all the ticket IDs from the ticket table, not a `List<Ticket>`. If you want a list of tickets, the query should be

```
select t from Ticket t
```

You should also strive to recpect the Java naming conventions: `ticketId`, not `ticket_id`.

Comment: I think you just pointed out the real mistake I was making. Actually the query was supposed to be a complex query with data taking from two tables but it was always giving me error ,i.e., because I was retrieving a different set of data into List<Ticket>... so here I was trying to breakdown to a simple query and see where was the problem.thank you!

Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep that in mind.